# Zeros of the derivatives of a finite Blaschke product.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

Let $B$ be an $n$ degree finite Blaschke product.  By considering the level curves of $B$, one can show that $B'$ has $n-1$ critical points in the disk (counting multiplicity).  Is anything known about the higher derivatives of $B$?  For example, the number of zeros of $B'',B''',\ldots$ in the disk?

Comment: Doesn't the Gauss-Lucas theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) implies that the zeroes of $B''$ are in the convex envelope of the zeroes of $B'$ and so on?

Comment: No, only for polynomials, not finite Blaschke products.

Comment: By considering the logarithmic derivative of a finite Blaschke product doesn't the proof follows exactly the same lines?

Comment: Even if this were the case, it would not answer the question of higher derivatives.  You cannot re-apply the "Gauss-Lucas for finite Blaschke products because the derivative $B'$ will not in general be a finite Blaschke product.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio For example, $z/(z^2+1)$ has only one zero at the origin, but critical points are elsewhere. Gauss-Lucas does not generalize to rational functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's of interest, particular after a so long non active term.
There is a analogue of Gauss-Lucas theorem for Blaschke-Products $B$:
It says, that the critical points lie in the non-euclidean convex hull of the zeros of $B$.

I have read it in "Polynomials Versus Finite Blaschke Products" Tuen Wai Ng, Chiu Yin Tsang. Here is the link: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-5341-3_14.