# Counting zeros of the derivative of a Blaschke product

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are points in the unit disc $\mathbb D$ and
>   $$B(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{z-a_j}{1-\overline{a_j}z},$$
>   prove that $B'(z)$ has $n-1$ zeros in $\mathbb D$.

The argument principle comes to mind but $B''(z)/B'(z)$ is a mess and I could not see how to proceed. [Zeros of the derivatives of a finite Blaschke product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891246/zeros-of-the-derivatives-of-a-finite-blaschke-product) mentions level curves of $B$ but I'm not familiar with that technique.

Comment: In the interesting reference (http://www.icms.org.uk/downloads/Complex/Ng.pdf), there is a mention (dia number 2) that the result you are after has been proven by Walsh in 1952. But I have been unable to spot more precisely the publication.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Based on that paper I was able to find a complete proof in the book The Derivative of Finite Blaschke Products by Mashreghi.