# Derivative of Blaschke product is not zero

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, blaschke-products

To calculate the derivative of $$f(z)=\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{z-a_m}{1-\overline{a_m}z}$$ I have used $\frac{d}{dz}\prod_{m=1}^nf_m(z)=(\prod_{m=1}^nf_m(z))(\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{f_m'(z)}{f_m(z)})=f(z)(\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{1-|a_m|^2}{(1-\overline{a_m}z)(z-a_m)})$ where $f_m$ is one element in the product, but I do not know how to further simplify. In essence, I want to show that $f'(z)\neq0$ everywhere inside the unit disk, i.e. $|f'(z)|>0$.

I have seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964163/boundary-behaviour-of-finite-blaschke-products-on-the-unit-circle) that $|f^{'}(z)|=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1-|a_k|^2}{|z-a_k|^2}$ and would like to get to this form.

Comment: The derivative of a Blaschke product (with $n \ge 2$) *has* zeros in the unit disk, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891246/42969.

Comment: So is the formula for $|f'|$ from the other post wrong?

Comment: As I understand it from the other post, that formula holds *on the boundary* of the unit disk.

Comment: A simple example: $f(z) = \frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2} \cdot \frac{z+1/2}{1+z/2}$, $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, that example refuted the general claim I was trying to prove very nicely, namely that a Blaschke product of degree n would take any value that has absolute value between 0 and 1 at n distinct points inside the unit circle. (Take $f(z)=-1/4$ in your example)